# Hide an entire filter on Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, show-hide

[here my sample dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3WX3.png)
I have a data source with ‘City’ and ‘Department’ information divided by **area** (Europe, USA etc that I don’t want to change for the dashboard). I'd like to hide the second filter for a specific area.
Not all the areas have a ‘Department’.

Example:

**Area Europe** has both ‘City’ and ‘Department’ information, so I want to show both the filters on my dashboard.

**Area USA** has only ‘City’ information (‘Department’ value is NULL or blank), so I want to show only the ‘City’ filter on my dashboard.

If I would like to set the show/hide status of the ‘City’ filter, for instance, based on the value of ‘City’(if the value is not null or blank), how can I reach the goal?

Comment: see this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V120g74mjfQ&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I saw this video before, but it doesn't work for me. I don't have to select the value on the Area filter directly on the dashboard. The area has to be a constant once I access the dashboard on my website (with a calculated field or something like this).